# Unable to do an arithmetic calculation in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

probably not relevant. my laptop is win8.1, lenovo yoga11s. the excel version is excel 2010
I am doing this chem lab report and I need to do some simple arithmetic calculation.  I need to subtract the data in cell B25 (0.001) from that in D25(6.85*10^-5), so in another cell, I simply type "=D25-B25", but I get "#VALUE!". I believe it is a cell data type error. The original data type of both cell is general, so I changed the data type of the second to scientific, but to no avail. the excel indicating that "a value used in the cell is of the wrong data type" for D25(6.85*10^-5), but I seems unable to get to the right data type.

It is not a  big issue for this particular case since I can always calculate myself, but I would love to know what went wrong and how to fix it
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D25, replace `6.85*10^-5` with `=6.85*10^-5`. You are missing  `=`. Generally bear in mind that even numerical formulas are still formulas. :-)